# Convert this Apache rewrite to Nginx rules

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to convert this .htaccess rules to nginx rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ navigation.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:%{HTTP:X-Requested-With}]
```

I used [this](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/) online conversion tool, which gives:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /navigation.php;
}
     HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:$http_x_requested_with;
#ignored: "-" thing used or unknown variable in regex/rew
```

However the result is not usable in nginx 0.76, and I got an error saying

```
unknown directive "setenv"
```

And when I eliminate the last line from my nginx config, the script fails to show some pages.

So I really appreciate if you could do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

With Nginx you do not need to remap exactly the way you did it in Apache.

Did you ever read the [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) nginx page?

To test a file is not a static file or directory before applying a rule in nginx the real simple way is not a multi-if like you did but a try_file directive ([check if file exists in pitfall page](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls)).

So you should start with that "rule":

```
server {
  root /var/www/domain.com;
  location / {
    HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:$http_x_requested_with;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /navigation.php;
  }
}
```

Now you have maybe some other locations to handle PHP files via fastcgi, this is maybe the real place where you need to transfer the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH as a `fastcgi_param`.

Comment: Well, while your point about not using 'if' is valid, but what I am concerned here is getting a working set of rules. I don't think that at this point worriying about the optimal nginx syntax is an issue, as nginx hardly can be a bottleneck for a php app. Unfortunately your suggested syntax gave an error, saying that 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:$http_x_requested_with;' was not known

Comment: Not using if is not a problem of 'optimization', if is not doing what you might expect, it replaces the location... The problematic line is the only I copied from your example, remove it. And have you tried fastcgi_param?